# Distressed text: photoshop like effects in LaTeX tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is  it possible to create a "distressed" look using TikZ? For example:

[image]

Note that it is akin to a filter over the text/image, as each letter looks different.

Comment: As you say, it looks like a filter over the text.  I'd do that by creating a semi-transparent picture over the top using some noise to create the effect.  Have you tried something like this?

Comment: Looks like a job for `\pgfmask`. Still I think it's much more easier with Photoshop or Fireworks.

Comment: @percusse "...easier with Photoshop or Fireworks" I _completely_ agree (though I'd use Inkscape myself). However, coming to this site I've been blown away at seeing how far LaTeX and TikZ can be pushed. I put the question out there to see if it was possible - the advantage with a TeX centered solution though is the ability to generate this effect on the fly!

Comment: @AndrewStacey no I haven't, and only because I'm not sure how I can do that with with TikZ (or any other package). Can TikZ create a "mask" that is generated by text?

Comment: @Hooked I was thinking the other way around: render the text first, and then put a translucent image over the top.

Comment: @Hooked I think my comment went to the wrong way. There is nothing wrong with your question. What I am trying to say is that you have to produce the mask together with the image. The mask is not defined via TikZ. See the manual for `\pgfmask` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant in the comments with fadings.  To do it properly, one should use a more random pattern than I do, so it's a proof-of-concept rather than an actual method.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=distress]
\node[text=transparent!0] {\Huge \textbf{Distressed Text}};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[preaction={fill},pattern color=DarkRed,pattern=crosshatch dots] (-4,-1) rectangle (4,1);
\fill[pattern color=IndianRed,
  pattern=crosshatch,
  path fading=distress,
  fit fading=false
] (-3.5,-1) rectangle (3.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: distressed text]